# Multiple triggering of keydown event

Tags: jquery

The following code is a simplified version of a maths puzzle I'm creating. The problem is this - once the 'inc' variable has been reset to '0' (line 25) the value of the input **$('#userInput').val();** is no longer displayed in the #testMessage div.

```
<body>

<input type="text" id="userInput">

<div id="testMessage"> </div>

<script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
var inc=0;

init();

function init(){
  $('#userInput').focus();

  $('#userInput').bind('keydown',function(event){
    var keyCode = event.which;
    if( keyCode == 13 ){ // RETURN KEY ...
      var user_ans = $('#userInput').val();

      $('#testMessage').html( user_ans );
      $('#userInput').val('');
      $('#userInput').focus();

      if( inc > 2 ){ inc=0; }
      init();
    }
  });

  inc++;
}

</script>

</body>
```

If I add a count variable and an alert to the script, I notice that the keydown event is triggering multiple times:

```
<body>

<input type="text" id="userInput">

<div id="testMessage"> </div>

<script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
var inc=0;
var count=0; // NEW VARIABLE

init();

function init(){
  $('#userInput').focus();

  $('#userInput').bind('keydown',function(event){
    var keyCode = event.which;
    if( keyCode == 13 ){ // RETURN KEY ...
      var user_ans = $('#userInput').val();

      $('#testMessage').html( user_ans );
      $('#userInput').val('');
      $('#userInput').focus();

      alert( count++ ); // NEW ALERT

      if( inc > 2 ){ inc=0; }
      init();
    }
  });

  inc++;
}

</script>

</body>
```

Please explain what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

You're binding the keydown event over and over again when the user hits the return key.

Comment: How can I stop the keydown event binding over and over again?

Comment: don't call the init function again.